C# linq Include OrderBy
I need some help sorting data by Included data. In the example below, I am returning a purchase order where I want to sort the purchase order line items by the line item id.
return await context.PurchaseOrders
            .Where(x => x.PurchaseOrderNumber == PurchaseOrderNumber)
            .Include(x => x.PurchaseOrderLineItems.OrderBy(x => x.LineItemId))
            .ProjectTo<PurchaseOrderDetailDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

The data returned looks like this
{
    "purchaseOrderId": 1,
    "purchaseOrderNumber": 10776,
    "supplierNumber": "86087319",
    "supplierName": "SANOFI AVENTIS HEALTHCARE PTY LTD",
    "storeNumber": 101,
    "departmentId": 10,
    "orderDate": "2019-02-27",
    "deliverBy": "2019-03-13",
    "created": "2024-07-08T08:17:28.0300376",
    "orderTotal": 123748.02,
    "orderStatus": "Open",
    "receivedStatus": null,
    "purchaseOrderLineItems": [
        {
            "lineItemId": 10,
            "purchaseOrderId": 1,
            "productId": "CW_2477705",
            "productDescription": "Essentials Barrier Cream 300g Jar",
            "uom": "Each",
            "quantity": 204,
            "unitPrice": 6.63,
            "lineTotal": 1352.52,
            "gstPercentage": 10.0,
        },
        {
            "lineItemId": 8,
            "purchaseOrderId": 1,
            "productId": "CW_2478048",
            "productDescription": "Essentials Barrier Cream 75g Tube",
            "uom": "Each",
            "quantity": 240,
            "unitPrice": 3.35,
            "lineTotal": 804.0,
            "gstPercentage": 10.0,
         },
        {
            "lineItemId": 16,
            "purchaseOrderId": 1,
            "productId": "CW_2480590",
            "productDescription": "Selsun Blue Replenishing Anti Dandruff Shampoo",
            "uom": "Each",
            "quantity": 2160,
            "unitPrice": 4.63,
            "lineTotal": 10000.8,
            "gstPercentage": 10.0,
        }
    ]
}

The OrderBy on the following line doesn't appear to be working
.Include(x => x.PurchaseOrderLineItems.OrderBy(x => x.LineItemId))

Any ideas on how I can solve this?
Thanks for your help.

Can you sort the list later?

You can do like this.
var purchaseOrders = await context.PurchaseOrders
            .Where(x => x.PurchaseOrderNumber == PurchaseOrderNumber)
            .Include(x => x.PurchaseOrderLineItems)
            .ProjectTo<PurchaseOrderDetailDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

purchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderLineItems = purchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderLineItems.OrderBy(x => x.LineItemId).ToList(); 

return purchaseOrders;


Thanks mate...Just noticed a typo.... purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrders should be purchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderLineItems Otherwise brilliant. Works perfectly.  Thanks for your help. You're a legend!

The point of the question is that EF ignores the Include (and hence the ordering) because the query ends in a projection. You better indicate that in the answer and remove the Include.
